# ID and class with numbers - Good or bad?

Tags: javascript, css, class, numbers

If we speak micro optimization of javascript and CSS. Does it matter if the class or ID contains numbers? Just a silly thought, since I don't know how it works behind the scenes.

**Will forexample:**

```
#d1
#d2
#d3
```

and

```
.d1
.d2
.d3
```

**Be better/worse than:**

```
#da
#db
#dc
```

and

```
.da
.db
.dc
```

I know that you can't start a class or ID with a number...

Comment: I know you are looking for optimization but just a comment: both are Terrible approaches, you are way better of giving them a sensible descriptive name so that when you read the CSS you can make any form of distinction and add meaning to the different classes. Your approach feels like it is going to be a maintenance disaster in the future. IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all. They're all treated as strings of characters. As an example, look at the [WebKit source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/dom/Element.h&d=4&gs=cpp%3aWebCore%3a%3aElement%3a%3agetIdAttribute%28%29@chrome/trunk/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/dom/Element.h%257Cdef&gsn=getIdAttribute&l=503).

```
inline const AtomicString& Element::getIdAttribute() const
{
    return fastGetAttribute(document()->idAttributeName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reasonable names so that programmers can maintain that. For Example if you are displaying a generic error message you can use class `error-message` which the programmers understand.

You can save bandwidth by using [Http Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). Also javascript compressor replace the variables names into a small variables with length of 1-3. You can also configure web server to compress static content (js, css), in addition to minimization done by compressor.

Comment: Thanks. Google Page Speed can be added to the list :)

Answer (score 0):

you just can't start the ID with a number I think

Answer (score 0):

I use numbers in ids all the time to specifically address items of a ul list for instance. There is no problem with that at all.

```
<ul>
<li id="user_1">User: Chris</li>
<li id="user_2">User: Steve</li>
<li id="user_3">User: Frank</li>
</ul>
```